# Scala - Cake Pattern + Typeclasses + Implementations needing constructor parameter

Tags: scala, typeclass, cake-pattern

Here is a bit of code I've distilled down as much as I can:

```
trait CakeLayer[A] extends {
  // typeclass hack to make it play nice with traits
  implicit def requireTypeclass: MyTypeclass[A]
  val typeclassInVal = requireTypeclass

  /* other stuff */
}

class FooImpl

object FooImpl {
  implicit object FooImplIsTypeclass extends MyTypeclass[FooImpl]
}

// This works perfectly
class Foo extends CakeLayer[FooImpl] {
  override def requireTypeclass = implicitly
}

// This gives me NullPointerException
// Occurs in a function of my "Bar" that contains an anonymous function
// which uses typeclassInVal. it is the first access to that val
// probably due to the parameter in the typeclass constructor?
class BarImpl(x: Int)

object BarImpl {
  class BarImplIsTypeclass(x: Int) extends MyTypeclass[BarImpl]
}

class Bar(x: Int) extends CakeLayer[BarImpl] {
  val typeclass = new BarImpl.BarImplIsTypeclass(x)
  override def requireTypeclass = typeclass
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply variable initialization order, which start with ancestors.

First,  `typeclassInVal` in ancestor trait is initialized. To do that, `requireTypeclass` is called. It is overriden in `Bar` and access `val typeclass`, not yet initialized, so null at this point. So `typeclassInVal` is initialized to null once and for all, and you get an NPE the first time it is used.

Simple workaround could be not having a val, but just a def in the ancestor trait, or having a lazy val.

Comment: That did it! Definitely need to work on learning more about how variables are initialized during class construction.. thanks!

Comment: lazy val is a potential deadlock http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=yLbdw06tKPQ